# Changing values on click for DC.JS Pie Chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Is there any way for me to have my pie chart display different values when it's clicked on? Right now, I have this but it's a no-go:

```
  var ndx = crossfilter(experiments),
  runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return ""+d.location;})
  speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.amount ;});

chart
.width(768)
.height(480)
.title(function(d){return d.value;})
.slicesCap(4)
.innerRadius(100)
.dimension(runDimension)
.group(speedSumGroup)
.ordinalColors(['#1f78b4', '#b2df8a', '#cab2d6','#bc80bd'])
.legend(dc.legend())
.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
    return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
    })
})
.on('transition', function(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
        return d.data.key + ' ' + d.value;
    })
})
chart.render();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display different values"? Do you want the text labels of the selected slices to change?